# Can't git clone Heroku project after reinstalling OS

Tags: git, heroku, authorization

I reinstalled my OS and now when I try to git clone my project it says that the key with a certain fingerprint is not authorized to access the project. Then it says fatal error and the remote end hung up.

What do I do about the fingerprint so that I can get back authorized access to my project?

Answer (score 1):

This link should help you: [Managing Your SSH Keys](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)

Your SSH key has been changed after you reinstalled your OS, so you have to add the new one to heroku.

1. If your new OS has never created a ssh key, `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. List current heroku keys `heroku keys`
3. Remove the old key (if you want) `heroku keys:remove older@oldOS.local`
4. Add the new one `heroku keys:add` (will upload ssh public key from /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide heroku with the public key after you generate an ssh key. Heroku will do that for you:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart